# Class 'Log' not found

Tags: lumen, lumen-5.2

I'm new to Lumen and Laravel, but I have to write a REST API using Lumen. I've set up a controller and I'm having a problem using the logger.
I've followed the documentation: [Lumen docs](https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/5.2/errors#logging)

This is my controller app/Http/Controllers/DocumentsController.php:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Log;

class DocumentsController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        Log::info('test');
        return response()->json(['result' => 'Oh hey!']);
    }
}
```

If I run this I'm getting an error saying:

**FatalErrorException in DocumentsController.php line 22: Class 'Log' not found**

So there seems to be something wrong with the Log facade (not quite sure how those work yet in Laravel/Lumen).

But if I change the Log::info() call, to manually pull the log service out of the DI container then it works:

```
    $app = app();
    $app->make('log')->info('test');
```

Any ideas as to why the facade method as described in the official documentation isn't working?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Doh and of course 5 minutes after posting this question I figured it out. I noticed in the Application base class (vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Application.php) the following aliases:

```
public function withFacades()
{
    Facade::setFacadeApplication($this);

    if (! static::$aliasesRegistered) {
        static::$aliasesRegistered = true;

        class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth', 'Auth');
        class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache', 'Cache');
        class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB', 'DB');
        class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Event', 'Event');
        class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate', 'Gate');
        class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log', 'Log');
        class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue', 'Queue');
        class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema', 'Schema');
        class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL', 'URL');
        class_alias('Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator', 'Validator');
    }
}
```

This method was never called however, because in bootstrap/app.php the $this->withFacades() call is commented out by default.

I uncommented it and now it works.