# "Laravel 'artisan' command produces no output" ... an interesting discovery which might explain what's going wrong

Tags: laravel, laravel-artisan

I've been beating my head against the problem (Laravel 5.2 on Windows 10 ...) that the `php artisan` command produces no output.  I finally started debugging by creating an `artisan2` file which prints in-progress messages, and which uses `try..except` to try to catch any errors.  Well, first I found this:

- `php  artisan2 -V` ran to the point where the `$kernel` object tries to run the command, then quit.  No exception is thrown; the program simply stops, having never returned from the method-call.  But ... *hallelujah!* ...
- `php7 artisan2 -V` produced a traceback! *(The difference being PHP-5 vs. 7.)*

`Exception Caught!  It is: 'Class log does not exist'
    #0 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(734): ReflectionClass->__construct('log')
    #1 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(629): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('log', Array)
    #2 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('log', Array)
    #3 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(849): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('log')
    #4 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(804): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolveClass(Object(ReflectionParameter))
    #5 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(774): Illuminate\Container\Container->getDependencies(Array, Array)
    #6 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(629): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\Exceptions\...', Array)
    #7 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('App\Exceptions\...', Array)
    #8 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(230): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('App\Exceptions\...', Array)
    #9 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(731): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
    #10 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(629): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure), Array)
    #11 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(697): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Illuminate\Cont...', Array)
    #12 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(1178): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Illuminate\Cont...')
    #13 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(261): Illuminate\Container\Container->offsetGet('Illuminate\Cont...')
    #14 \vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel.php(117): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->reportException(Object(Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError))
    #15 \artisan2(42): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
    #16 {main}`

It looks to me like Laravel has done *something* to suppress error tracebacks, presumably so that it can send it to a logger ... but it can't create the logging class ... and so it doesn't produce anything at all.

Now, I don't yet know *why* `Class log does not exist` on this project, when it *does* exist (that is, "the `artisan` command runs ...") on a blank new project.  I'd love for anyone to quickly tell me what the difference might be.  ***How is this supposed to work? How does Laravel auto-construct that class?***

Nevertheless, this discovery might cast some light as to *why* the `artisan` command can "exit without producing any output," as we see being reported here on SO at various times over the past few years.

Comment: I found this while searching SE and am evaluating what it says about "Class log not found."  Stay tuned ...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37759276/class-log-not-found  *(But my environment isn't Lumen ...)*

Answer (score 0):

Well ... I never did figure out why this wasn't working for my particular (old ...) project, but I *did* discover that running `composer install` (not `update`) made the problem disappear.  And, at this point, really the only thing that matters to me is that it finally *did* disappear.  I really don't know what changes `composer` made so that, suddenly, `artisan` worked again.

(I also found it necessary in my environment to explicitly specify PHP-7.)